# Find my coordinates from distance with unknown coordinates

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangulation

I am trying to work out if there is a way to calculate some coordinates relative to each other simply by knowing $3$ or more distances from some unknown points.

I do not have a distance matrix, I simply have distances from myself to $3$ or more points. These distances are calculated from signal strength, not geometry.

For instance, if I am given
\begin{align*}
d_1 & = 7.0711\\
d_2 & = 2.8284\\
d_3 & = 3.1623
\end{align*}
I assign my location as $(0,0)$.

Then I move somewhere, recalculate and find my new distances are 
\begin{align*}
d_1 & = 7.6158\\
d_2 & = 5.6569\\
d_3 & = 3.1623
\end{align*}

These are real values and I know from plotting some points and calculating distances that the second set means my new location is $(2,2)$. Is there some way to calculate this from knowing only the two sets of distances and assigning myself a point of origin?

Note : I have searched already and most questions were related to distances and known points or distance matrices so I don't think I'm asking a duplicate question.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please see this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to format mathematics on this site.

Comment: Get some more distances from different positions, then have a look at [Multilateration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilateration) or [Trilateration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilateration)

Comment: Yes I'm aware of trilateration but the issue is the same. I'll have 3 positions (with unknown coordinates) with 3 sets of distances to 3 points with unknown coordinates. What I'm trying to do is essentially work out the distance between two sets of distances if this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two measures do not suffice. Consider that the observer takes three successive  positions $(0,0),(a_1,0),(a_2,b_2)$ ($b_1=0$ to prevent rotations). The data are the $9$ associated distances to the vertices of the unknown triangle $ABC$. There are also $9$ unknowns: $a_1,a_2,b_2$ and the coordinates of $A,B,C$. The solution is not unique because the whole figure is invariant by symmetry with respect with $O$ and by symmetry with respect with $Ox$.

EDIT 1. In fact, there are $8$ figure-solutions and $4$ solutions for $a_1$ -of the form $(\alpha,-\alpha,\beta,-\beta)$-. In particular, the distance between the first and second position of the observer is not uniquely defined!! Moreover, the minimal polynomial of $a_1$ is not solvable; in particular, the figure is not constructible with ruler and compass.

EDIT 2. Answer to Matt. Consider that the observer takes only two successive  positions $(0,0),(a_1,0)$. The data are the $6$ associated distances to the vertices of the unknown triangle $ABC$. Unfortunately, there are $7$ unknowns: $a_1$ and the coordinates of $A,B,C$. Thus there are an infinity of solutions (in particular for $a_1$).

Comment: The solutions are all loosely equal to each other though aren't they? If A, B and C are fixed then the two sets of distances refer to two unique points. Isn't all that changes the coordinates of A, B and C?

For my problem, if I could find a solution just for a1 (i.e. the distance between the two sets of distances) then that would help me greatly. Is this possible?